# Создать список с элементами akn

Tags: python, python-3.x

Создать список с элементами `akn=n f (k) + sin (k) g (n)`, где k, n = 1, 2, 3, 4;

```
f[k] = int((cos*k/2,7)+9,1(1,2*k+1))
g[n] = int((sin*n/3,12+cos*pow(n, 2))-8,3*sin*3*n)
```

Вывести его на экран в виде таблицы. Элементы списка равные нулю, заменить на 1. Найти сумму элементов под главной диагональю.
Помогите составить программу. Не понятно как сделать чтобы печаталось таблицей.

Comment: То есть с заполнением списка у вас не возникло трудностей?

Comment: Пример печати ascii-таблицы: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/cfe998c3d45f6f1f664bd8801db097fd7e4232cc/ascii_table__simple_pretty__rjust.py

Comment: У меня вообще со всем вопрос. Так как даже представления не имею как это написать.

Comment: Поэтому у меня и возник вопрос. Я не совсем понимаю как это делать. Школа закончена давно, но от неё мало чего запомнилось... Это сейчас и вызывает некоторые трудности. Только поэтому и попросил помощи.